# Hard Disk not shown

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, hp, hp-proliant

I'm trying to install windows server 2012 on a new HP proliant ml350 gen10.

There's two hard drivers in it, but they are not shown in the installation list (the screen where I have to pick a hard drive to install windows on).

Like I said, it is the first installation on this server, can you provide me with help, or detailled instruction for what I have to do to solve this issue

Comment: It sounds like you need to install the driver for the hard drive controller. If you use the HP SmartStart installation media you can install the OS with that, which will include the needed drivers.

Comment: do i have to be online to do such thing ? because i'm not connected to the internet

Comment: @joeqwerty when the bios is loaded I can see my hard drive and their storage capacity

Comment: Yes, of course the server can see the hard drives, but Windows can't because Windows needs a driver for the hard drive controller. You need to use the HP SmartStart installation media to install Windows. If this is a new server it should have come with SmartStart.

Answer (score 2):

First, the ML350 is likely to have a RAID storage controller. Blank HDDs won't show up unless you define a logical drive on top of the physical drives, depending on your performance and availability requirements.

Second, the OS might need an appropriate driver for the storage controller. Using the included Smart Start DVD should provide that driver, using another DVD requires you to insert and load the driver when selecting the destination disk.

Comment: Thank you for you reply sir, but there is no CD or DVD reader in my server I only have USB.

Comment: Internal optical drives are optional usually, you can use an external USB drive just as well. The server should have included a Smart Start CD/DVD medium initially. If you don't have one you can download from HPE and burn it or put it on a USB stick.

Comment: As Zac67 said above, you can use a USB DVD drive, and there's software that can burn DVDs to USB sticks. Try [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) or a similar tool.